# Pictures disappear when I scroll down in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView for display posts, I have 3 different post types (Text,Image and Video). I`ve added an imageview to cell and Im using if else codes in cellForItemAt function for display imageview for Image and Video posts or hide it with heightAnchor = 0 for text posts.

its loading correct at beginning, but when I scroll down and scroll up again images heightAnchor resetting to "0" for every posts. How can I solve this issue ?

When the posts are loaded

[image: When the posts are loaded]

When I Scroll down and scroll up again

[image: When I Scroll down and scroll up again]

TimelinePosts CollectionViewCell

```
class TimelinePosts: UICollectionViewCell {

    let avatar: UIImageView = {
        let avatar = UIImageView()
        avatar.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        avatar.clipsToBounds = true
        avatar.layer.cornerRadius = 24
        avatar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return avatar
    }()

    let name: UILabel = {
        let name = UILabel()
        name.numberOfLines = 1
        name.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return name
    }()

    let content: ActiveLabel = {
        let content = ActiveLabel()
        content.numberOfLines = 0
        content.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return content
    }()

    let image: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return image
    }()

    let time: UILabel = {
        let time = UILabel()
        time.numberOfLines = 1
        time.textColor = .gray
        time.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        time.textAlignment = .center
        time.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return time
    }()

    let moreButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        let image = UIImage(named: "arrow")
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()


    let favoriteButton: FaveButton = {
        let button = FaveButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 28, height: 28), faveIconNormal: UIImage(named: "favorite"))
        button.normalColor = UIColor(hexString: "#CBCBCB")
        button.selectedColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FFBE00")
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    let boostButton: FaveButton = {
        let button = FaveButton(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 28, height: 28), faveIconNormal: UIImage(named: "boost-pressed"))
        button.normalColor = UIColor(hexString: "#CBCBCB")
        button.selectedColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()

    let actions: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.numberOfLines = 1
        view.textAlignment = .left
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addViews()
        setupViews()
    }

    func addViews(){
        addSubview(avatar)
        addSubview(moreButton)
        addSubview(time)
        addSubview(name)
        addSubview(content)
        addSubview(image)
        addSubview(favoriteButton)
        addSubview(boostButton)
        addSubview(actions)

    }

    func setupViews(){

        avatar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        avatar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        avatar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
        avatar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true

        moreButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
        moreButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        moreButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14).isActive = true
        moreButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14).isActive = true

        time.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        time.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        time.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48).isActive = true
        time.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        name.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatar.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        name.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: moreButton.leftAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
        name.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        name.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 73).isActive = true
        content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -46).isActive = true
        content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: name.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        image.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 73).isActive = true
        image.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -46).isActive = true
        image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: content.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120) * 2) / 3).isActive = true

        actions.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatar.rightAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        actions.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: moreButton.leftAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
        actions.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: image.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        actions.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        actions.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        favoriteButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        favoriteButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        boostButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -14).isActive = true
        boostButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: favoriteButton.topAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        boostButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
        boostButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true


       /* name.backgroundColor = .yellow
        content.backgroundColor = .red
        image.backgroundColor = .green */

    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And cellForItemAt function

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TimelinePosts", for: indexPath) as! TimelinePosts

            if indexPath.row < id.count{

            cell.avatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: avatars[indexPath.row]))

            cell.time.text = hours[indexPath.row]

            cell.favoriteButton.isSelected = isLike[indexPath.row]
            cell.favoriteButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.favoriteButton.tag = indexPath.row

            cell.boostButton.isSelected = isBoost[indexPath.row]
            cell.boostButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.boostButton.tag = indexPath.row

            let selectedArrowTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.selectedArrow))
            selectedArrowTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            cell.moreButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.moreButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.moreButton.addGestureRecognizer(selectedArrowTap)


            cell.content.customize { label in
                label.text = content[indexPath.row]
                label.hashtagColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
                label.mentionColor = UIColor(hexString: "#6e00ff")
                label.URLColor = UIColor(hexString: "#0366d6")
            }

            cell.content.handleHashtagTap { hashtag in
                print("Success. You just tapped the \(hashtag) hashtag")
            }

            cell.content.handleURLTap { url in

                let urlString = url.absoluteString

                if urlString.hasPrefix("http://")
                {
                    let openURL = URL(string: urlString)!
                    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: openURL)
                    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else if urlString.hasPrefix("https://")
                {
                    let openURL = URL(string: urlString)!
                    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: openURL)
                    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                else
                {
                    let openURL = URL(string: "https://" + urlString)!
                    let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: openURL)
                    self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

            }



            if types[indexPath.row] == 2{
                cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.row]))
                let selectedImageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.photoZoom))
                selectedImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
                cell.image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.image.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.image.addGestureRecognizer(selectedImageTap)

            }else if types[indexPath.row] == 3{
                cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/\(self.extractYoutubeIdFromLink(link: videos[indexPath.row])!)/mqdefault.jpg"))

                let playBtn = UIImageView()
                playBtn.image = UIImage(named: "youtube-play")
                playBtn.tag = indexPath.row
                playBtn.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.videoPlay)))
                playBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                playBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                cell.image.addSubview(playBtn)

                playBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.image.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                playBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.image.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
                playBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 74).isActive = true
                playBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52).isActive = true



            }else{
                cell.image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
            }
}

            return cell
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest you make two different cells. One for text with images and a second one for only text. Then deque depending on the data that you have in your dataSource. It’ll make your life much easier and your cellForItem will also become cleaner.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla thanks, I made it like you said but I thought maybe there will be easiest way to do it. Thanks again :)

Comment: That’s actually the easiest way. It might seem as unnecessary extra coding but it is actually worth it :). Good luck!

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, thanks for info, too you :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not modify image height by

```
cell.image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

create a new variable `imageHeightConstraint` in you `TimelinesPosts`,

set this variable in `setupViews()`

`imageHeightConstraint = image.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120) * 2) / 3).isActive = true`

then change the height by this

```swift
// don't miss this code.
imageHeightConstraint.constant = ((UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120) * 2) / 3
if types[indexPath.row] == 2 {
//***************     
} else if types[indexPath.row] == 3 {

//***************     

} else {
    imageHeightConstraint.constant = 0  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, @GaloTorresSevilla said "you must to create different cells for each types, that method is most clean and easiest way." So, I created new cells and its working well now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView is parent UICollectionView.  You use UIScrollView with UIScrollViewDelegate for setup images with va scrollOffset: CGFloat follow .y (referent code)

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var scrollOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    // process with scrollOffset
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, @GaloTorresSevilla said "you must to create different cells for each types, that method is most clean and easiest way." So, I created new cells and its working well now. Thanks again :)